# toolkit:ListPicker - styling the expansion box

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have an application with the background set to black. In this application I want a `toolkit:ListPicker`.

The problem is that the ListPicker uses the theme of your phone to set the background of the expansion box which contains all the items. The result is as follows:

**Dark theme in phone:** Everything works as expected. The Listbox is gray, when I tap it a white box expands, containing all the items.

**Light theme in phone:** The Listbox is black (and now invisible), the text is also black (and invisible). When I tap the box I can see the selected item in blue, and the rest of the items are, yes, black and invisible.

The Background property only sets the background of the Listbox, not the expansion box that appears when i tap the Listbox.

Is there any way whatsoever to style the expansion box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem mate,that what fix my problem was this [article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/listpicker-fullscreen-mode-background-problem-workaround).

and a word of advice check what happens to the textbox if you have one

Comment: Thanks, it is also doable with the help of Expression Blend. Similar to what is explained in this article: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australia/windows-phone-7-using-listboxes-with-style/1192