# ListPicker background when expanded + light theme

Tags: c#, themes, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, listpicker

I'm having some trouble getting my `ListPicker` to look right when I switch my device theme to **light**. As you can see from the screenshots below, it looks fine with a **dark** theme, but it appears transparent with a **light** theme.

Start:

[image]

Expanded with dark theme:

[image]

Expanded with light theme:

[image]

**[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400728/toolkitlistpicker-styling-the-expansion-box)** seemed promising, but it appears to only apply to the `FullScreenMode`. Plus, in **[this article](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/listpicker-fullscreen-mode-background-problem-workaround)**, which the answer links to, describes updating the `Expanded` Visual State, which doesn't seem to exist when I open my page in Blend and edit a copy of the template. Here is my XAML which is very simple:

```
<Grid x:Name="OptionsGrid" Grid.Row="1">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height=".05*" />
      <RowDefinition Height=".15*" />
      <RowDefinition Height=".05*" />
      <RowDefinition Height=".15*" />
      <RowDefinition Height=".13*" />
      <RowDefinition Height=".15*" />
      <RowDefinition Height=".15*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width=".40*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Text="Test 1: " FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

   <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpTest1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
      <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 1"/>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 2"/>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 3"/>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 4"/>
      </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
   </toolkit:ListPicker>

   <TextBlock Text="Test 2: " FontSize="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

   <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpTest2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
      <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 5" />
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 6" />
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 7" />
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 8" />
      </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
   </toolkit:ListPicker>
</Grid>
```

Also, in the code-behind, I've got this code which forces the top `ListPicker` to be on on top of the bottom one when expanded:

```
lpTest1.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 2);
lpTest2.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 1);
```

Is there a way around the background color issue I'm experiencing above? Changing the `Background` property only changes the background color of the non-expanded view.

Comment: The white color in both themes is the default behavior for Windows Phone, my question goes to why are you changing the ZIndexProperty of the controls? You should leave the ZIndex to the system to manage...

Comment: If I remove my z index code, the bottom listpicker is visible through the top one when the top one is expanded (dark theme). That was the only workaround I could find.

Comment: Also, is what you see in screenshot #3 default behavior? It doesn't seem like the control should be transparent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `StackPanel` instead of the `Grid` control and specify `Margin` on the other controls to set spacing between them.

Something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Test 1: " FontSize="20" Margin="12,0" />

    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpTest1" Margin="12,0">
      <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 1"/>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 2"/>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 3"/>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 4"/>
      </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>

    <TextBlock Text="Test 2: " Margin="12,0" />

    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpTest2" Margin="12,0">
      <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 5" />
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 6" />
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 7" />
         <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value 8" />
      </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is indeed what fixed my problem as you can see in my own answer above.

Comment: Good point, I replied by mobile so didn't spot your own answer!

Comment: I'll give it to you, since you provided the code sample! I was lazy in my answer post, so this will be much more helpful to anyone who looks here in the future. Thanks again!